# Heroku having trouble finding npm in $PATH

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Procfile is

```
web: npm start
```

Error log shows

```
 app[web.1]: bash: npm: command not found
```

Package.json is being parsed fine, install works fine. What's the next step for diagnosing?

Comment: You'll probably have to show your package.json and possibly push/install messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use `node path/to/your/server.js` rather than `npm start` as a passthrough.  Node is guaranteed to be executable in the $PATH.

Try copy/pasting the script used with `npm start` into your `Profile`, and see if it works!

Comment: what if I made a `prestart` hook?

Comment: Which is exactly how I just found this issue